# Error displaying page in OpenCart

Tags: opencart

Hello I am new in OpenCart and I am studying it now for my next project. And My first step in learning this framework? is to display my own page using a link from my navigation menu in admin area. But I am getting this error.

> Notice: Error: Could not load template C:\wamp\www\myshop/admin/view/template/locations/countries_list.tpl! in C:\wamp\www\myshop\system\engine\controller.php on line 90

And I can't spot my error. Here's what I did.

Here's my controller `/controller/locations/countries.php`

```php
<?php

class ControllerLocationsCountries extends Controller {

        private $error = array();

        public function index() {

            $this->language->load('locations/countries');
            $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
            $this->getList();
        }

        protected function getList() {

            $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

            $this->template = 'locations/countries_list.tpl';
            $this->response->setOutput($this->render());

        }
}
```

Here's my simple view `/view/template/locations/countries_list.php`

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Then in my header I include this code for displaying a link in menu navigation `/controller/common/header.php`

```php
$this->data['text_locations'] = $this->language->get('text_locations');
....
$this->data['locations'] = $this->url->link('locations/countries', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
```

That's all. I don't know what part is wrong. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty self explanatory. The template file doesn't exist. Make sure the template filename and path is exactly the same and that you're using `.tpl` as the extension and not `.php`. It's also possible there could be a permissions error, but on `WAMP` that's not likely